# get dataframe based on join on existing field from other dataframe

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi guys i have dataframes with the following structure , what i would like to do is to get data from the table histoachat where  SITE should be in pos and FRN should be the id of supplier dataframe and the CODA should be in the table article

```
 histoachat.printSchema()
        pos.printSchema()
        supplier.printSchema()
        article.printSchema()
        pos.printSchema()
    root
     |-- SITE: decimal(5,0) (nullable = false)
     |-- FRN: string (nullable = true)
     |-- CODA: string (nullable = true)
     |-- QT: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
     |-- PB: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
     |-- REMI: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
     |-- PNETTVA: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)
     |-- SCH: decimal(38,0) (nullable = true)

    root
     |-- id: long (nullable = false)

    root
     |-- id: long (nullable = false)

    root
     |-- id: long (nullable = false)

    root
     |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

Here what i did i still get foreign key issue , the final dataframe will be inserted in a postgresql table that contains the three foreign keys SITE,FRN and CODA

```
   val test_Pos = histoachat.select($"SITE" as "pos_id").except(pos.select("id").distinct())
     val supplier_Test = histoachat.select($"FRN" as "frn_id").except(supplier.select("id").distinct())
    val article_Test = histoachat.select($"CODA" as "art_id").except(article.select("id").distinct())
     val finalHistoachat = histoachat.except(exRows)
```

Any help thanks 
Here the issue i got

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an **expensive solution** for you i.e. by using `join`

```
val finalHistoachat = histoachat.as("histo").join(pos.as("pos"), $"histo.SITE" === $"pos.id")
                                                .drop($"pos.id")
                                                .as("joined1")
                                                .join(supplier.as("sup"), $"joined1.FRN" === $"sup.id")
                                                .drop($"sup.id")
                                                .as("joined2")
                                                .join(article.as("art"), $"joined2.CODA" === $"art.id")
                                                .drop($"art.id")
```

I hope the answer is helpful and until you get some light answers this answer should help you get the final dataframe you desire

Comment: thanks a lot for helping , you mean expensive on term of time execution ?  what is the problem of my solution ? Thanks

Comment: Yes I mean expensive in terms of execution time. I didn't test your code though as I saw that your requirement cannot be met with what you've tried. And as far as I know you can't query two tables without joining them in spark scala.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear friend